# Ansible variable call in template

Tags: templates, variables, ansible

Here is the issue:

I have a playbook:

```
 tasks:

- include_vars: vhosts_vars.yml


- name: SSL vhost creation
  template: src=templates/proxy_ssl_vhost.DOMAIN.j2 dest=/etc/httpd/vhosts.d/ssl_{{ item.servername }}.conf
  with_items:
    - "{{ proxy_apache_vhosts_dev }}"
```

and vars in vars/vhosts_vars.yml

```
    proxy_apache_vhosts_dev:
    - {servername: www.DOMAIN.com , machinename: domainsrv, documentroot: /var/www/html, vhost_ip: 1.2.3.4, vhost_name: DOMAIN.com.conf,  serveradmin: "webmaster@domain.com" }


   proxyPass:
    - {dev: DOMAINdev , qual: DOMAINqual , prod: DOMAINprod}
```

Now, in my template, I also try to access the variables in ProxyPass, like: dev, qual or prod.

However, when I put this in my template:

`{{ item.proxyPass.dev }}`

It say that it's undefined... But, the other top variables are OK...
I know that the items in proxy_apache_vhost_dev are "called" in the playbook via the "with_items:".... But How do I do to directly call the one in ProxyPass ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you only have a single item in the list then the task will run once, with `item` set to this value:

```
{servername: www.DOMAIN.com , machinename: domainsrv, documentroot: /var/www/html, vhost_ip: 1.2.3.4, vhost_name: DOMAIN.com.conf,  serveradmin: "webmaster@domain.com" }
```

Using `{{ item.proxyPass.dev }}` in your template throws an error because there is nothing named 'proxyPass' in that above value of the variable `item`.

If you want to simply reference your `proxyPass` variable then just remove the 'item.' prefix from the front of it:

{{ proxyPass.dev }}

Answer (score 0):

In your situation there's no need to use `with_items` (that said, nothing stops you from doing it) as `proxyPass` and `proxy_apache_vhosts_dev` are two separate variables. 
If you want to access proxyPass using `{{ item.proxyPass.dev }}` you could define your vars this way:

```
proxy_apache_vhosts_dev:
    - {
         servername: www.DOMAIN.com ,
         machinename: domainsrv,
         documentroot: /var/www/html,
         vhost_ip: 1.2.3.4,
         vhost_name: DOMAIN.com.conf,
         serveradmin: "webmaster@domain.com",
         proxyPass: {
            dev: DOMAINdev,
            qual: DOMAINqual,
            prod: DOMAINprod
            }
     }
```

With this definition, `proxyPass` will just be another element of the `proxy_apache_vhosts_dev` var, and you will be able to access it as `{{ item.proxyPass.dev` if using `with_items` or as `{{ proxy_apache_vhosts_dev.proxyPass.dev }}` if not using `with_items`